# Add satellite layer on top street layer

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

how can I programmatically add satellite layer on top of street layer for example.
This demo used a pre-defined style [Mapbox GL toggle satellite without setting style](https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/995de3964b179bd4c283d79cf42ece03) to achieve what I want, but I would prefer a programmatically demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add the satellite layer as you would any other layer.

```
map.addLayer({
  id: 'satellite',
  source: {"type": "raster",  "url": "mapbox://mapbox.satellite", "tileSize": 256},
  type: "raster"
}, 'optional_before_argument');
```

http://jsbin.com/cucemulala/1/edit?html,output

Comment: This works, but beware that the street layer is still active underneath the satellite layer. This means that as you pan around, you're downloading the tilesets of *both* the satellite layer and the (hidden) street layer, which will cost ~2x the bandwidth and $ that you actually need. What you'd probably prefer is to set the visibility of the entire base map to 'none' whenever the satellite view is visible. I don't know how to do that cleanly.